# Android, check if back Button was pressed

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, back

i have two views and activities. 
On the first there is a spinner. On the second, you can create new entries (Stored in database for the spinner in activity 1). 
If the user is finished and pressed the back button, i have to refresh the spinner on activity 1 (because of the new entries).

Ist there a possibility to check, if the app returns to activity 1, because the back button in activity 2 was pressed?

I know, i can do it with the onResume Method, but this method is called EVERYTIME i return to activity one and not ONLY because of the back button.

I want to refresh the spinner only when the back button was pressed.

Any solution? Can i Check if the back button was pressed in the onResume method?

Comment: you can override onBackPressed() in second activity and in that method you can update your database entries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed()` in the Second Activity. This will get called when the user presses the back button.

You can pass the information as a boolean `hasBackPressed = true` in the `setResult()`

Starting Activity 2 from Activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Passing info back from Activity 2:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("hasBackPressed",true);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Receiving data in Activity 1:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            boolean hasBackPressed = data.getBooleanExtra("hasBackPressed");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seams to be a possible good solution. For some reason, my onActivityResult in activity 1 is not called when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Allright, it was because i did not start the second activity with startActivityForResult(i, 1), but startActivity.I think i understand now, how this is working.One more comment: data.getStringExtra("hasBackPressed"); is a String, not a boolean.Thank you.

Comment: Ya. My mistake. It should be `data.getBooleanExtra()` and that returns `boolean`. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can start Activity 2 for result, using `startActivityForResult()`. On Activity 2 you can set the result to `RESULT_OK` when new items have been added. Then, in the `onActivityResult()` method of Activity 1 you can check the returned result and update your data, if needed.

Comment: `On Activity 2 you can set the result to RESULT_OK when new items have been added` adding to this line -> And you can even set it on back press from activity 2

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method and take the action inside this function.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your stuff here

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult()` to start the second activity, and return some value in the `onBackPressed()` of the second activity. Catch that in `onActivityResult()`, and refresh the spinner there.

Look into [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).